# Is an HMAC based on a second-preimage resistant hash function always unforgeable?

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, hmac, mac, 2nd-preimage-resistance

If hash function is collision-resistant, then its associated HMAC is always unforgeable.  But suppose that a hash function is only second-preimage resistant, not necessarily collision-resistant.  Then my question is, its associated HMAC always unforgeable?

Comment: Collision resistance $\implies$ 2nd-preimage resistance of hash functions. That is $p \implies q$. See [the law of contraposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition) $\neg q \implies \neg p$

Comment: @kelalaka Yes, collision resistance implies second preimage resistance.  But second preimage resistance does not imply collision resistance.  So I'm asking.  If a hash function is second preimage resistant, is its associated HMAC unforgeable?

Comment: AFAIK, collision resistance alone is *not* sufficient to prove the security of HMAC. The original [Bellare _et al._ 1996](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.134.8430) paper proves the unforgeability of HMAC assuming both collision resistance and the unforgeability of the compression function of the hash when viewed as a MAC acting on fixed-length messages (and the later [2006 paper](https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/hmac-new.html) removes the collision resistance assumption, under slightly stronger assumptions about the compression function).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even collision resistance is not sufficient to make HMAC unforgeable, so neither is second-preimage resistance.

Let $H : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^n$ be a collision resistant hash function. We define the hash function $H' : \{0,1\}^* \to \{0,1\}^{n+1}$ as
$$H'(m\Vert b) = H(m)\Vert b,$$
where $|b|=1$.

Since for any $m_0\Vert b_0$ and $m_1\Vert b_1$, it holds that $H'(m_0\Vert b_0) = H'(m_1\Vert b_1)$ if and only if $b_0=b_1$ and $H(m_0)=H(m_1)$, it is easy to see that any collision in $H'$ implies a collision in $H$. Thus $H'$ must remain collision resistant.

However, HMAC instantiated with $H'$ is easily forgeable.

\begin{align}
\mathsf{HMAC}(K,m\Vert b) =& H'\Bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{opad})\Vert H'\bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{ipad})\Vert m\Vert b\bigr)\Bigr)\\
=&H'\Bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{opad})\Vert H\bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{ipad})\Vert m\bigr)\Vert b\Bigr)\\
=&H\Bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{opad})\Vert H\bigl((K\oplus \mathsf{ipad})\Vert m\bigr)\Bigr)\Vert b\\
\end{align}

I.e., an adversary can take the tag $t$ for some arbitrary message $m$, and present $(m\oplus 0\dots01,t\oplus 0\dots01)$ as a valid forgery with probability $1$.